# How can I resolve this? The unit type exists in two dll files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dll, controller

I am currently going through a tutorial using Visual Studio 11 beta. When trying to set the max length of a field value in one of my classes:

```
[MaxLength(50)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

It errors out and wont let me compile because the `MaxLength()` function exists in two places:

> Error  4   The type '**System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**.MaxLengthAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 11\ContosoUniversity\packages\EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'

I have tried to remove both files but that just causes more issues because other code in my project is dependent upon them.

Is there a way I can tell it to use one or the other?

**All of these approaches don't seem to be working for me.. Refer to the comments under the answers..  Any other ideas?**

Thanks

Comment: What about the full name space, Are they the same too?

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It looks like some if not all of your answers would work out.  I'll be able to test it on my other computer tomorrow and then choose an answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is till not working, the system still detects two occurrences of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute                And I tried to create an extern Alias via the command prompt - by going to the dll and typing /r:GridV1=grid.dll but It didn't recognize the command or something.

Comment: @L.B When the error message says that two types with the same fully namespace qualified name exist in different assemblies, it won't help to supply the full namespace. It is the same in both cases. His problem is that he references too many assemblies, and he gets duplicates from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qualify the attribute with the desired namespace

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength(50)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I still get "Error 2 The type or namespace name 'MaxLength' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"  And it still exists in both locations "Error 3 The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 11\ContosoUniversity2\packages\EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'"

Comment: Obvoiusly it is in the same namespace in both libraries. It is not a good idea to reference two different versions of the same library. Remove one reference if you can. Otherwise use the procedure that I described in this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/10841652/880990 to resovle the namespace clash.

Comment: I was having trouble understanding until I read the article in your other post. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Just Uninstall EntityFramework from packages and reinstall it(EntityFramework). It works for me. Just follow the steps mentioned below:

[image: 1.Right click on reference 2.Click on manage nugetpackages]

1.Right click on reference 2.Click on manage nugetpackages.

[image: 3.Click on Uninstall]

3.Click on Uninstall

4. go in online section and type entity frame work in search box 5. Click on install button

[image: 4. go in online section and type entity frame work in search box 5. Click on install button]

Comment: Yep, this is the only solution that worked for me, and it also avoids having to add extra code, aliases etc.

Comment: This also worked for me.  In my case, I had upgraded my project from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.  And my Error List was showing a couple of nugget packages (including EntityFramework specifically) needed to be reinstalled as a result.  It presented that as a Warning, but I ignored it until your post.

Answer (score 6):

Use using at the top of your code:

```
using MaxLength = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

Comment: When I try this I still get this error "Error 1 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' is not an attribute class"

Comment: Then simply reference it's fully qualified name ;).

Comment: Giving the full namespace with the name is of no use when both types have the same fully namespace qualified name. He should check if he references too many assemblies. In the ***unlikely*** case that it is really a good idea to reference two distinct assemblies which both have a `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute` class, he should use `extern alias ThisOneHere;` and then `[ThisOneHere::System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength(50)]` as suggested by Martin Ernst's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case, if you are getting the same error in latest environment (VS 2017/.NET Framework 4.6.x) and with Entity Framework like 6.1 or 6.2, here is the solution;

Downgrade your Entity Framework to 6.0. It'll work.

Answer (score 1):

MaxLength is not a function, it's an Attribute. 
You can use the using directive in each file to specify the current correct context.
Or just type the full namespace, e.g. `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength`

Answer (score 1):

Try using extern alias http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx to differentiate between the two assemblies

Also check out http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/07/4502.aspx near the bottom of the page is an example

Comment: I tried going to the dll and assigning an alias but I got a the following error  "the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect."

Answer (score 1):

This question is now the top SO answer for this question so I figured I would answer it generally here.

The `The type 'BLAH' exists in both` error often pops up in the following occassions:

**1. DUPLICATE FILES** - (often very simple) This is notoriously the case with .dll files. In most cases of duplication, deletion of one of the duplicate files is the easiest and best solution

**2. NON-DUPLICATE FILES** - (more complicated, such as the original poster's case) you unfortunately need to edit and often recompile/find alternate versions of the files so that conflicts like this do not arise. Luckily more often than not, qualifying the attribute with the same namespace will fix conflicts like this.

*For example if your code is conflicted on something called `MaxLength` that is mentioned in several files, then qualify it on necessary files to make it very clear which MaxLength you want to use like so:  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength`. This should help to clear things up, so nothing gets conflicted when trying to run your code*