# Can't compile c# project because of some tuple error when referencing an external dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, tuples, sharp-snmp

I have an error, when I try to build my .net 4, c# project. Everything works great, but when I add an external reference to a given DLL, it stops working, it can't build, throws this type of some errors:

> Error 36 The type 'System.Tuple' exists in both 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' and 'C:\Projects\Project1\ExternalRefernces\SharpSNMP\SharpSnmpLib.dll' C:\Projects\Project1\CheckerStore.cs 17 21

Note, I did not do anything with the new library, just added as a reference. Any ideas?

Comment: Evidently `SharpSNMP` provides their own implementation of that type that is colliding with the system provided one.  (probably for backwards compatibility)  Do you have the option of not referencing `SharpSnmpLib.dll`?

Comment: No, I must reference it, I need it to implement a new feature of my project.

Comment: Which version are you using?  Even better, can you provide the URL to the download?

Comment: Thx. This is the download link: http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/downloads/get/316104

Comment: Yep, those types are in that dll and the author provides no other implementation for .NET 4.0.   Not sure what the author is thinking, but you could always download the project, rip out that folder, and build your own dlls.

Comment: Then why they say here http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/ .net 4 is supported. OK, I know I should ask them. Bad news, it is not easy to compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is either change the target version to 3.5 or make some changes in the SharpSNMPLib. The source can be fetched from [here](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib) or [here](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/releases).

The changes you need to make is specifically moving the System.Tuple type somewhere else.

**Edit:**
I belive you have added a reference to a precomplied DLL. A DLL that is NOT compiled for framework version 4. What you need to do is download the source code (see links above) and compile the project with target version 4.

Why you need to do this is because there are conditional build parameters depending on the framework target version. The SharpSNMPLib System.Tuple is used for version <= 3.5 and the framework System.Tuple is used for version >= 4.

**Edit:**

- Reproduced your problem using framework System.Tuple and SharpSNMPLib.dll.
- Successfully built SharpSNMPLib targeted on version 4.
- Successfully built application using framework System.Tuple and the new SharpSNMPLib.dll.

Comment: I don't understand. They say SNMP Library supports .net 4: "Support .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, 4.0, .NET Compact Framework 3.5, and Mono 2.8+." http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/ in the middle of the page

Comment: +1. This is the advantage of open souce software; however, don't forget to document all your changes to the library, since you might want do use a more recent version of it in future and you will have to make these changes again.

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this problem by specifying an external alias. Select the SharpSNMP reference in your project. In the properties window change `Aliases` from `global` to say `SharpSNMP`. In your code type this

```
extern alias SharpSNMP;

...

System.Tuple<T1,T2> sysTulpe;
SharpSNMP::System.Tuple<T1,T2> sharpTulpe;
```

or

```
extern alias SharpSNMP;

using SharpSystem = SharpSNMP::System;

...

System.Tuple<T1,T2> sysTulpe;
SharpSystem.Tuple<T1,T2> sharpTulpe;
```

See [Aliases: overcoming name conflicts part 2: extern alias](http://www.davidarno.org/c-howtos/aliases-overcoming-name-conflicts-part-2-extern-alias/)

Comment: Will not work since SharpSNMPLib tuples are not exactly the same as Framework 4 Tuples.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: You may be right that they don't work the same way; however, this is not the point here. It's about resolving the namespace clash. The OP can choose the `Tuple` variant that he wants.

Comment: Yes he can. However if he already extensively uses the framework System.Tuple and decides to alias to SharpSNMPLib Systen.Tuple he has some rewriting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to your `CheckerStore.cs` file, line 1721 (if I'm right). Find the `Tuple` class, and reference it using it's **fully qualified name**.

Comment: That won't work.  It's the exact same fully qualified type name.  (read the error message, specifically `System.Tuple` exists...)

Comment: Are you saying that you have *namespace clash*?

Comment: @Saeed, did you read my first comment to the OP's question?  It should pretty clearly explain to you what's going on and why there's a collision.

Comment: Yeah, I see. It's truly weird. I've never seen fully qualified name clash.

Answer (score 1):

The library for some reason re-implements some system types. Likely reason is to make code to be source level compatible when using older versions of the framework.

Most likely there is a version of this SharpSNMP library that works with 4.0 framework. Check if you already have correct on in your source tree. Check with creators of the library what versions of the assembly you need to use with given framework version and what is recommended way of doing it.